# WiFi hotspot turns off by itself + WiFi turns on by itself

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, huawei

My honor 8 lite (Android 7.0) started to do strange stuff:

1. While WiFi tethering works, and my PC is connected, the tethering turns off after a few minutes.
2. Even after turning WiFi off, it turns on by itself.

**Apps permissions:**
[image]

**Additional permissions**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rogue app is turning the Wi-Fi ON. Look into the Permissions.

[image]

In *Change Wi-Fi Connectivity*, you can find list of all apps which can create such problem. Disable all of them or do trial & error.

**Edit:**
If you can't find this list in Settings, install [this tiny app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ackmaniac.apppermission), go to Permissions tab and tap `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` to get the list. This app doesn't let you remove permission, but after knowing the information about an app, you can disable its permission through app's *App Info* in Settings.

Comment: @Dorad Go to Additional Permissions..

Comment: Thanks @Android Popsicle, look again at my edited question.

Comment: @Dorad Edited the answer.